# Problem is package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

What could be wrong here?

```
/opt/local/lib/node/.npm/embedly/0.3.2/package/package.json:1
"name": "embedly
      ^

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
13 Apr 02:23:06 - [ERROR] SyntaxError
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

package.json

```
{ "name": "embedly"
, "version": "0.3.2"
, "description": "Embedly client library for node"
, "homepage": "https://github.com/embedly/embedly-node"
, "keywords": []
, "author":
  { "name": "Bob Corsaro"
  , "email": "bob@embed.ly"
  , "url": "http://www.google.com/profiles/rcorsaro"
  }
, "repository":
  { "type": "git"
  , "url": "git://github.com/embedly/embedly-node"
  }
, "bugs": { "web": "http://github.com/embedly/embedly-node/issues/" }
, "directories":
  { "doc": "./docs"
  , "lib": "./lib"
  , "test": "./test"
  }
, "dependencies": {"hashish": "", "qs": ""}
, "devDependencies": {"vows": ">= 0.5.6"}
, "main": "./lib/embedly.js"
, "scripts": { "test": "vows" }
, "bin":
  { "embedly_oembed": "bin/embedly_oembed.js"
  , "embedly_objectify": "bin/embedly_objectify.js"
  , "embedly_preview": "bin/embedly_preview.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like missing double quote, but it will help to show us the package.json file.

Comment: I updated the post with the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown from the statement

```
_package = require('embedly/package.json')
```

It's a bug and I'll have it fixed shortly.

Comment: ? How do you fix that statement? Shouldn't you be able to require package.json?

Comment: The fix was to require('./package.json')

Answer (score 1):

Many things could be wrong there actually, are you sure the .json you receive is formatted correctly? It looks to me that you're missing a double quote, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, I just checked and the JSON is correct, it' a valid .json. Even though I don't think node.js is wrong, it may actually be that you're not decoding properly the file containing the JSON object. Maybe a problem related to the base64 / base32 library?